# What is different between subtotal and subtotal_invoiced

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders, sales-order, invoice

Sometimes I have seen in order in the `sales_flat_orders` table that have a `subtotal` but have no `subtotal_invoiced`. What is different between them?

Here is a sample row extracted from `sales_flat_orders` table:

```
subtotal     subtotal_invoiced    grand_total  total_invoiced    total_paid

37.5000           <null>            37.5000        <null>          31.2500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The _invoiced columns are used by Magento to keep track of how much of the original order has been invoiced.

Once you hit the "Invoice" button in the admin and submit the invoice you will find these columns updated.

Also of note: it is possible with Magento to only partially invoice an order (for example if you only have some items in stock).

Your example does show total_paid which seems unusual but could be related to how your current payment method handles this (in other word not creating an invoice upon receipt of payment).

Comment: Thank you @Kristof, so in this situation, we have total_due right? but in my record it's null again

Comment: I would expect total_due to be the subtotal before any invoices are created. Just to work out what is happening I would try with a different payment method first (Check / Money Order) for example and then compare it to the specific payment method that you are working with.